# why is Button expanded to android.widget.Button in android studio ? How do I make it work with Button only

Tags: java, android, button

I have been using android studio for about a week now. Earlier I could just type something like Button (an object) and it would work but now I have to write android.widget.Button to make it work. What should I do if I want to use Button only?

Also, if I simply type Button then android studio either converts it to android.widget.Button or shows an error saying that it cannot resolve Button

Comment: update your question with the  Activity code where this problem occurs

Comment: You have any other libarary class named button object. check your import statement in class. It seems Button object class already used by other library class.

Comment: You probably just forgot to add this line `import android.widget.Button;`

Comment: I have turned auto import on. So shouldn't android Studio automatically import whatever is necessary?

Comment: And... did it, actually?

Comment: No....It did not

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

> It seems button object class used by another library class

For Example take `fragment` class. It have named Fragment class but it have two versions of class `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` & `import android.app.Fragment;`.

You can import only one class. Suppose you import `import android.app.Fragment;` you can use `Fragment` which extends `import android.app.Fragment;` only. Then fragment with other version class you should use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Could you be more specific?